# Chrome doesn't render pure css overlay properly

Tags: css, google-chrome, hover, overlay, opacity

please have a look on the link below (make result window a lil bit wider though) and tell me why there're are still some white lines on top and on the sides of the boxes when hover overlay is fully loaded?  When I put the background image for that divs, problem still occurs (no matters if it's SVG or PNG file).

```
.link-picture-small {
position: relative;
display: block;
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
height: 17.5em;
background: #FFFFFF;§
background-size: 100%;
border-radius: 0.625em;
}

.overlay {
position: absolute;
display: table;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #FFFFFF;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #212121;
border-radius: 0.625em;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 1.15s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: all 1.15s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: all 1.15s ease-out;
        transition: all 1.15s ease-out; 
}

.overlay p {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.link-picture-small:hover .overlay {
opacity: 0.99;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hatK5/

I've got this problem using Chrome (latest version). This issue doesn't exist in Firefox and (very surprisingly!) in Safari.

Are there any clever techniques how to make it work properly in Google's browser?

Comment: It's better now but, if you make result window wider, you will still see white stripes on sides. Again, Chrome only. I want it to work nice on wider screen - that's why I'm continuing this topic.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because of the `display:table`.

I will suggest an approach but I'm not sure if this is the best.

**Remove**

`display: table;`

**Add**

```
padding-top: 50%;
box-sizing: border-box;
webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hatK5/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are positioning `.overlay` absolutely, you do not need to set its `display` to `table`.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hatK5/3/.

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #212121;
    border-radius: 0.625em;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: It's better now but, if you make result window wider, you will still see white stripes on sides. Again, Chrome only. I want it to work nice on wider screen - that's why I'm continuing this topic.

Comment: I just tested the code outside of the jsfiddle on a wide screen in Chrome 35 and it looks good.  Try giving the `.overlay` the `top: 0` and `left: 0` coordinates.  Also, when I applied a mini-reset: `* {margin: 0; padding: 0; }` even with a `display: table` the white outlines disappeared.  Give these a shot.

Comment: It doesn't help. The solution was to put `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` on `:hover` element. However I have no clue why does it help so if anybody would be so kind to explain I'd appreciate.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that I've realised what was the reason of the issue. Basically weird white lines were appearing when `opacity` value was less than `1`.